Sennheiser 450BT doesn't show up on blue tooth devices
While in pairing mode, my 450BT do not show up as a discoverable device on Ubuntu. There are other BT devices on the list so my laptop does detect bluetooth.
I have no issues connecting the headphones to my phone.
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. Integrated Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:b39a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

$ hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 18:5E:0F:69:D4:52  ACL MTU: 1021:5  SCO MTU: 96:6
    UP RUNNING 
    RX bytes:1785 acl:0 sco:0 events:228 errors:0
    TX bytes:42956 acl:0 sco:0 commands:227 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xfe 0x0f 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF 
    Link mode: PERIPHERAL ACCEPT 
    Name: 'DLTU'
    Class: 0x7c010c
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer, Audio, Telephony
    Device Class: Computer, Laptop
    HCI Version: 4.2 (0x8)  Revision: 0x1000
    LMP Version: 4.2 (0x8)  Subversion: 0x1000
    Manufacturer: Intel Corp. (2)



Please edit the question to include results from terminal for lsusb; hciconfig -a
